# Gradient Mesh in Inkscape?

Tags: 14.04, inkscape

I use Ubuntu 14.04 32 bits, and I want to use Gradient Mesh on Inkscape 0.48.5 r

I [watched here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=c73D8-I21oU) that exist a tutorial, but I didn't saw this resource in my Inkscape.

How can I enable this Gradient Mesh?

Thanks!

Comment: What is your version of Inkscape? This feature is in Inkscape version 0.48+devel r12483. I've got Inkscape 0.48.4 r9939 (from PPA, under 14.04 LTS) and this isn't yet available in my version.

Comment: @David My version is Inkscape 0.48.5 r

Comment: You don't mean Ctrl+F1 do you?

Comment: @JacobVlijm Yes I upgrade to Inkscape 0.91+devel r but I didn't found this Gradient Mesh.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have now got [0.91 from the Inkscape PPA](http://www.webupd8.org/2015/02/inkscape-091-released-with-new-renderer.html).

To enable access to gradient mesh editing (Ubuntu 14.04 LTS), I had to do the following. In Inkscape:

1. Go to `Edit > Preferences` (*or* `SHIFT-CTRL-P`), then `Interface > Keyboard Shortcuts`.
2. In "Search" look for `toolmesh` as search term.
3. That should leave **Context** with a drop-down toggle. Toggle it to reveal a line that says:

   Mesh ... Create and edit meshes
4. Click on the line in the "Shortcut" column, and choose your "accelerator" key combination (I used `CTRL-ALT-M`, fwiw).

Close the preferences dialog. Next time you click on an object, you can hit your key combination to put the gradient editor into "mesh-mode", as in the video linked by OP.

<sub>HT: [hulf2012 in the Inkscape forum](http://www.inkscapeforum.com/viewtopic.php?p=59690&sid=4f5953d5253e438c6ae0178bd55f0333#p59690)</sub>

Comment: Note that the gradient mesh tool in Inkscape 0.91 is considered unstable and might cause crashes, cfr. [this thread on Inkscapeforum, second post](http://www.inkscapeforum.com/viewtopic.php?f=5&t=18834&p=71685).